# Get property from object and check if it contains value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to use get property from object and check if that property contains certain value:

Method to get property looks like:

```
   public static object GetProp(object obj, string propName, value)
    {
        return obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(obj).Contains(value);
    }
```

This will get me object value.

And usage is (or actualy what i am trying to achive is):

```
     string value = this._predicateFilter.GetValueOrDefault(refName, string.Empty);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            predicate.And(c => Assets.Extensions.GetProp(c, "name", "value to compare"));
        }
```

I am getting an exception:

```
'object' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best
extension method overload 'Queryable.Contains<string>
(IQueryable<string>, string)' requires a receiver of type 
'IQueryable<string>'
```

And I think problem is something with linq and entity framework cant execute that method inside its body.

I could use nasty solution like:

```
        string firstname = this._predicateFilter.GetValueOrDefault("Firstname", string.Empty);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstname))
        {
            predicate.And(c => c.Firstname.Contains(firstname));
        }

        string lastname = this._predicateFilter.GetValueOrDefault("Lastname", string.Empty);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastname))
        {
            predicate.And(c => c.Lastname.Contains(lastname));
        }
```

Witch works fine but, i wold preffer less code, what am I missing?

Oh and im using

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Candidate>();
```

from linqKit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get property value from string using reflection in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You updated your code and added even more errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`PropertyInfo.GetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty(v=vs.110).aspx) returns an `object` which you are trying to use as an [`IQueryable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562(v=vs.110).aspx).

The code is telling you exactly what the error is `object` does not contain a (extension)method for `Contains`. Also in the updated code you missed the identifier off of `value` in the method signature and have the return type as `object` when you will always be returning a `bool`.

So fix those errors and before calling `Contains` cast it to an `IQueryable<T>`:

```
public static bool GetProp(object obj, string propName, string value)
{
    object o = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(obj);

    IQueryable<object> queryable = o as IQueryable<object>;
    if (queryable != null)
    {
        return queryable.Contains(value);
    }

    return false; //Some other default
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`Type.GetProperty` doesn´t return the properties *value*, but the [`PropertyInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) for that property itself. What you want is to get the properties value for a given instance - in your case for `obj`. So use this in your `GetProp`-method:

```
return obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(obj);
```

Comment: Aye it will get me value of the property, but will not remove exception

Comment: This is because `GetValue` just returns an `object`, You need to convert this to an `IQueryAble`. Anyway your edits turn this question in something completely new.

Comment: @HimBromBeere The updated code added more errors but the cause of the initial error is the same see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
public static bool PropEquals<TProp>(object obj, string propName, TProp valueToTest)
{
    return EqualityComparer<TProp>.Default.
       Equals(valueToTest, obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(obj));
}

...

string value = this._predicateFilter.GetValueOrDefault(refName, string.Empty);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
{
    predicate.And(c => Assets.Extensions.PropEquals(c, "name", "value to compare"));
}
```

The PropEquals returns a true or false depending on whether the property whose name you supplied is equal to the value that you supplied.